# how can the chef server know if a node's role was applied and its service is up and running?

Tags: chef-infra

If a node's role was defined as, for example, apache2, and assuming the chef-client checks every X seconds interval for changes, how can the chef-server know that the role was successfully applied and that the service defined by apache2 ( httpd ) is up/running ?

The use case for the above is to perform some orchestration, where roles are assigned and then some sort of loop checks to see if the service is completed and running, before proceeding to a next stage assigment.

Answer (score 2):

Consider enabling the [lastrun](https://github.com/jgoulah/knife-lastrun) handler, the code will set a number of [node attributes](https://github.com/jgoulah/knife-lastrun/blob/master/lib/lastrun_update.rb) that can be used to determine the state of the last chef client run.

Chef is a declarative language. One must assume that if the recipe states the service should be running and client completes without error, then the service is indeed running.

Another option would be to kick-start run the chef client using the [knife command](http://docs.opscode.com/knife_ssh.html)

```
knife ssh "role:webserver" "sudo chef-client"
```

This will ensure that all your nodes are properly converged.

Comment: I disagree. It's important to understand what's the domain of each tool to make the correct assumptions. The Chef Server will never know if a service is up and running. The most it can say is that the service did not fail to start. There's a difference there. Chef will know whether the command `service httpd start` returned `0` or not. It has no way to know whether that actually started the web server, or if it crashed soon after, or even if someone or some other process has stopped it. For that, you need monitoring.

Comment: Chef is a convergent technology. Your recipe describes your node's desired state and running chef-client will attempt to take the correct actions to ensure your server matches that state. That's good enough for me. Obviously if I don't trust chef, I can write my own chef resources or implement additional monitoring... Why not? One can never have enough monitoring.... For example who monitors the that the chef client is running?